# Can't set UIImageView image

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uiimageview, uiimage

I'm using an if statement to set a `UIImageView`'s image depending on the value of a variable. This is the statement:

```
- (void)configureView
{    
    if (self.detailItem) {
        if ([detailItem isEqualToNumber:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0]]) {
            [mapImageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"0.jpg"]];
            NSLog(@"derp");
        }
    }
}
```

"derp" gets printed but the `UIImageView`'s image won't change... If I put the `setImage:` statement in `viewDidLoad` it works fine. What am I doing wrongly?

Comment: when/where is your method called ?

Comment: In setDetailItem:

- (void)setDetailItem:(NSNumber *)newDetailItem
{
    if (detailItem != newDetailItem) {
        detailItem = newDetailItem;
        
        // Update the view.
        [self configureView];
    }
}

Comment: supposing "0.jpg" exist in the app bundle, try to log `mapImageView`.. Either it is `nil`, or its `frame` changed making it non-visible

Comment: Is this code run on the main thread? If not, it can cause a rather lengthy delay from the code being run until you see the change.

Comment: When I check the value of mapImageView it says it is null... What should I do to fix this? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My guess is you're calling the `configureView` method from a view controller's init method.

At that point the view controller's view has not been loaded, and the outlets for its subviews will still be `nil`.

Calling it from any of:

```
awakeFromNib
viewDidLoad
viewWillAppear:
viewDidAppear:
```

will work.

Try assigning

```
UIImage * image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"0.jpg"]
```

put a breakpoint there, and then look at the value in `image`, to make it's being assigned correctly.

Comment: Now mapImageView has a value but it still doesn't change the ImageView, and the NSLog has stopped working too.

Comment: Dude, if you want more help you need to start accepting some answers.

Comment: "NSImage *image" Should be UIImage *image, by the way.